# how to recive data in code codeigniter API from client side

Tags: php, laravel, api, codeigniter

I am trying to save data to database using API which i made in codeigniter but i am reciving null values through API.

I have website in laravel from which i am making request to api like this -:

```
$params = array(
            'service_name' => $service_name,
            'city' => $city,
            'enquiry' => $enquiry,
            'timezone' => $timezone,
            'cal_date' => $cal_date,
            'timing' => $timing,
            'fname' => $fname,
            'lname' => $lname,
            'email' => $email,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'country' => $country,
            'message' => $message,
            'ip_address' => $ip_address,
            'user_agent' => $user_agent,
            'added_date' => $added_date

            $API_URL ='http://crm.localhost/service/api_1';
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']]);
            $response = $client->request('POST', $API_URL, [
                'form_params' => $params
            ]);
```

And in codeigniter i have service controler in which i have written function for api_1 
This is how i am reciving data.

```
    public function api_1() {
            $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
            $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
            $service_name = $this->input->post('service_name');
            $city = $this->input->post('city');
            $enquiry = $this->input->post('enquiry');
            $timezone = $this->input->post('timezone');
            $cal_date = $this->input->post('cal_date');
            $timing = $this->input->post('timing');
            $country = $this->input->post('country');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');
            $ip_address = $this->input->post('ip_address');
            $user_agent = $this->input->post('user_agent');
            $added_date = $this->input->post('added_date');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CodeIgniter code seems to be ok.
So I imagine that the problem is in the code that sends the data in Laravel.

I suggest to add this code to your method, for testing purposes.

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST) ;  echo "</pre>";
```

Also, you could use something like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) to send fake values to the end URL to check the response.

Hope this info helps.